# onFiledSuccess and onFieldError doesn't work properly in Parsley.js

Tags: parsley.js

this code sets or removes class of the div when the input field is valid/invalid.

```
$( 'form' ).parsley(
    'addListener', {
        onFieldSuccess: function ( elem ) {
            elem.parent().removeClass('err');
            return true;
        }
    }
);


$( 'form' ).parsley(
    'addListener', {
        onFieldError: function ( elem ) {
            elem.parent().addClass('err');
            return true;
        }
    }
);
```

It doesn't work fine when I set more validators to one field, for example required and data min. Error message is visible but the class is removed and not set back again.

Thanks for any advice.